# Operações com dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

A planilha `resultados` foi gerada da seguinte maneira:

**1. Geração dos dados:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df_mat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(24, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])

df_por = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(18, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])

df_geo = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])

df_ing = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])

df_his = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(8, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])

df_fis = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(12, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])

df_qui = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(12, size=(100, 1)), columns=['Qt_acertos'])
```

**2. Concatenei os dados em uma única df:**

```
acerto_materia = [24,18,8,8,8,12,12] #É a quantidade máxima de acertos por matéria.

colunas = ['ac_mat', 'ac_por', 'ac_geo','ac_ing','ac_his','ac_fis','ac_qui']

resultados = pd.concat([df_mat, df_por, df_geo,df_ing,df_his,df_fis,df_qui], axis=1)
resultados.columns = colunas

numero_questoes = pd.DataFrame (np.array(acerto_materia)).T
numero_questoes.columns = colunas
per_acerto_por_aluno = (resultados/numero_questoes.iloc[0])*100


per_acerto_por_aluno
```

**3. Gerei o total de acertos por aluno:**

```
resultados['total_acertos'] = df_mat + df_por + df_geo + df_ing + df_his + df_fis + df_qui
resultados
```

**4. Gerei o percentual total de acertos por aluno:**

```
resultados['per_geral'] = (resultados['total_acertos']/90)*100
resultados
```

**5. df `resultados`:**

|  | ac_mat | ac_por | ac_geo | ac_ing | ac_his | ac_fis | ac_qui | total_acertos | per_geral |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 35 | 38.888889 |
| 1 | 19 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 8 | 48 | 53.333333 |
| 2 | 14 | 16 | 0 | 5 | 7 | 4 | 4 | 50 | 55.555556 |
| 3 | 10 | 7 | 3 | 4 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 32 | 35.555556 |
| 4 | 7 | 2 | 2 | 7 | 0 | 9 | 3 | 30 | 33.333333 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 99 | 11 | 15 | 0 | 1 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 42 | 46.666667 |

A partir do df acima, os alunos abaixo foram desqualificados.

```
    rep_mat = resultados.loc[resultados['ac_mat'] == 0, 'ac_mat']
    rep_fis = resultados.loc[resultados['ac_fis'] == 0, 'ac_fis'] 
    rep_qui = resultados.loc[resultados['ac_qui'] == 0, 'ac_qui'] 
    reprovados = pd.DataFrame(rep_mat + rep_fis + rep_qui)
    reprovados[0] = 'Desqualificados'
    print(reprovados)
```

|  | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Desqualificados |
| 6 | Desqualificados |
| 10 | Desqualificados |
| 12 | Desqualificados |
| 14 | Desqualificados |
| 20 | Desqualificados |
| 25 | Desqualificados |
| 26 | Desqualificados |
| 27 | Desqualificados |
| 33 | Desqualificados |
| 35 | Desqualificados |
| 49 | Desqualificados |
| 56 | Desqualificados |
| 65 | Desqualificados |
| 66 | Desqualificados |
| 72 | Desqualificados |
| 73 | Desqualificados |
| 74 | Desqualificados |
| 84 | Desqualificados |
| 89 | Desqualificados |
| 92 | Desqualificados |
| 94 | Desqualificados |
| 98 | Desqualificados |

**Minha Dúvida é: Como faço para construir um novo dataframe somente com os alunos `desqualificados`, porém com todas as colunas do df `resultados`?Não estou conseguindo acessar a coluna dos alunos.**

Esse é resultado que preciso:

|  | ac_mat | ac_por | ac_geo | ac_ing | ac_his | ac_fis | ac_qui | total_acertos | per_geral | Aprovado |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | 7 | 7 | 3 | 1 | 8 | 3 | 35 | 38.888889 | Desqualificados |
| 6 | 19 | 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 11 | 8 | 48 | 53.333333 | Desqualidicados |
| 10 | 14 | 16 | 0 | 5 | 7 | 4 | 4 | 50 | 55.555556 | Desqualificados |
| ... |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O que eu faria é criar uma nova coluna no dataframe de resultados com a informação de desqualificado ou não e filtraria somente os desqualificados. Seria algo como:

```
resultados['estado'] = np.where((resultados['ac_mat'] == 0) | (resultados['ac_fis'] == 0) | (resultados['ac_qui'] == 0), 'Desqualificados', '')
reprovados = resultados.loc[resultados['estado'] == 'Desqualificados']
```

Caso não queira criar uma nova coluna no dataframe de resultados, pode também criar uma cópia dele, com `novo_dataframe = resultados.copy()`.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).